# Android ASyncTask Crashing on Android 4 and below

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I am using `ASyncTask` to do simple animation in my app. But it only works on Android 5.0+, below that it just crashes and says that I edit UI from the wrong thread. Here is my code:

```
private class AlphaCorrect extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Integer> {
    float alpha;
    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Integer[] params) {
        Log.i("back","running");
        for (float i = 0.0f; i < 0.9; i += 0.02) {
            alpha = i;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Update();
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        for (float i = 0.8f; i > -0.1f; i -= 0.02) {
            alpha = i;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Update();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Log.i("run", "RUN");
        canClick = false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        canClick = true;
    }

    protected void Update() {
        correct.setAlpha(alpha);
    }
}
```

I tried `Runnable`, `Thread` and some other things already. Any ideas?

Comment: logcat please ? display exact error message .

Comment: I wonder how it worked on Android 5.0+. You are indeed not allowed to do anything with UI from any thread other than main. Whenever you need to update the UI just post a Runnable on *main thread* (if the system doesn't provide a callback for you).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do exactly what the error says - you update UI from another thread. Override `onProgressUpdate` method of AsyncTask, put `Update()` inside it and call `publishProgress(0)` in your doInBackground method

Comment: I was doing that and it was same. Same error message.

Answer (score 0):

you can not edit any ui of the activity from the do in background of any asynctask. thats why you are getting this error. the values you can edit from the doinbackground is local verables and global veriables.

you can not edit the ui from doInBackground().

the sloution would be to use [onProgressUpdate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onProgressUpdate(Progress...)) and do the ui changes in the onpogressupdate() .

let me know if this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

it just like their say.you cann't update anything in your Update(), you should use the onProgressUpdate()，this method provide by AsynTask.